# new Date() function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Does anyone has any idea why

```
new Date('2012','1','1')
```

returns 1 february 2012 instead of 1 january?

and

```
new Date('2012','0','1')
```

will return 1 January 2012

Is this weird or logical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's exactly what section 15.9.1.4 of the ECMAscript specification (3rd edition) says should happen. 0=Jan, 1=Feb, ... 11=Dec.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: or, if you want a more 'easy to read' documentation (;-) have a look at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Please take some time to read the document of JavaScript Dates below:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

It has noticed that :

> JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

So the result you got is absolutely correct.